# python3-config --configdir shows older version of python

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to compile `vim` with my python `3.7` but it seems it relys on either python 2.7 or 3.5.

While I installed python3 and `python3 --version` returns `3.7` but `python3-config --configdir` shows python `3.5`

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

How can I get rid of python 3.5 and its stuff.

Also:

```
python3.7-config --configdir
```

returns:

```
No command 'python3.7-config' found, did you mean:
 Command 'python3.5-config' from package 'python3.5-dev' (main)
 Command 'python2.7-config' from package 'python2.7-dev' (main)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this later problem by `sudo apt install -y python3.7-dev`. However, one should use `python3.7-config`